# Issues while trying to form regex of Json string

Tags: json, regex

I am facing issues trying to form regex of the following string.

```
[{"Column1":"Value1"},{"Column2":"Value2"},{"Column3":"Value3"},{"Column1":"Value4"},{"Column2":"Value5"},{"Column3":"Value6"},{"Column1":"Value7"},{"Column2":"Value8"},{"Column3":"Value9"}]
```

and I want output as

```
[{"Column1":"Value1","Column2":"Value2","Column3":"Value3"},{"Column1":"Value4","Column2":"Value5","Column3":"Value6"},{"Column1":"Value7","Column2":"Value8","Column3":"Value9"}]
```

I tried with `(?!^)^(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)|\}(?!$)(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` but it is either removing all opening braces or all closing braces.

This output formation, is it at all possible from regex ? or are there any other options except split, remove, replace string?

Comment: Do you want to split at every third column, or do you want split at "Column1"?

Comment: Every third column so that `{"Column1":"Value1"},{"Column2":"Value2"},{"Column3":"Value3"}` become `{"Column1":"Value1","Column2":"Value2","Column3":"Value3"}` and so on

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to parse a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to replace each group of three, and use capture groups so you can recompose the JSON with just the data you need.

```
var input = @"[{""Column1"":""Value1""},{""Column2"":""Value2""},{""Column3"":""Value3""},{""Column1"":""Value4""},{""Column2"":""Value5""},{""Column3"":""Value6""},{""Column1"":""Value7""},{""Column2"":""Value8""},{""Column3"":""Value9""}";

var re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(\{[^}]+)\},\{([^}]+)\},\{([^}]+)\}");
var output = re.Replace(input, "$1, $2, $3 }");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

It is probably best to use Newtonsoft.JSON to parse and rebuild your JSON, otherwise if the format of the string isn't followed exactly as described then this solution will break.  You can accommodate some variance by adding `\s*` before and after each brace so that whitespace is accounted for, but otherwise this is a brittle solution.

Comment: I tried with JParse from newtonsoft but was unable to do so thought of going by regex